# Why can't I update its element value correctly within Array.forEach() loop in Angular 7?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm testing Material Table(mat-table) on Angular 7, here's a weird issue I ran into.

Send a request to jsonplaceholder for fake data in users.service

```
export class UsersService {
    API_BASE = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getUsers(): Observable<object> {
        const url = this.API_BASE;
        return this.http.get(url);
    }
}
```

Because jsonplaceholder only returns 10 rows of data, so I concatenate the data for a larger array, say, 30 rows for testing pagination feature with ease. Meanwhile, update the 'id' field with iterate index so the 'id's looks like 1,2,3...30, instead of 1,2,3...10,1,2,3...10,1,2,3...10, which is a result of concatenation, that's it, nothing special.

users.component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((users: UserData[]) => {
        users = users.concat(users, users);
        users.forEach((user, index) => (user.id = index +1));
        console.log(users);
        this.dataSource.data = users;
    });
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Although the table shows up beautifully, but the 'id's column looks weird, they are not 1,2,3...30 sequentially, instead, they are 21,22,23...30,21,22,23...30,21,22,23...30

[image]

I tried to print out the user.id inside the forEach loop, it's all good.

```
    users.forEach((user, index) => {
        user.id = index + 1;
        console.log(user.id);
    });
```

[image]

Where did I go wrong with this? Any clue? Thanks.

P.S, API used in the code: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Comment: `users = users.concat(users, users);` you're concatenating the same array. Is this intended?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, yep, jsonplaceholder API always returns the same data array, I don't think I should repeatedly call the API, yes I did that intentionally, but I did tried pass the users array to different array variables, then concatenate them, same result, and if I console.log(users) after the concat(), the array is nothing special or wrong, weird thing happens after the forEach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even though you have 30 array elements after concatenating the array twice, you still only have 10 unique objects. the Object behind users[20] is the same as users[0], so you override the id of the already processed objects from index 10 to 29

you can fix this by creating a copy of each object. There are many ways too do this. a very simple way is serializing and deserializing using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse:

```
users.forEach(user => users.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))));
```

Comment: Sounds solid, I didn't aware of that, thanks bro, any suggestion? Tried push(), same result, maybe I shouldn't mock an object array like this?

Comment: you must clone the object. you can do it by using JSON.stringify JSON.parse:
users.forEach(user => users.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)) );

by serializing and deserializing you create a completely new Object which is not connected to the source anymore.

Comment: @A.Winnen Ah, you're perfectly right, how stupid I am, thank you so much.